# Redirect to route with DATA in Laravel 5

Tags: parameters, routes, laravel-5

I know how to send data to a route redirect, what i don't know is how to get that data in the route controller function...

I dont mean url parameters, i mean **data**. I need this because i receive some data in a post route and i want to resend it to a get route.

Here's the function of a post route where i redirect to another get route:

```
return \Redirect::route('publicReservacionPasoDos', ['comidas' => $comidas, 'bebidas' => $bebidas]);
```

The other route controller's function is this:

```
public function pasodos()
{

    $horas = [
        '4:00',
        '4:30',
        '5:00',
        '5:30',
        '6:00',
        '6:30',
        '7:00',
        '7:30',
        '8:00',
        '8:30',
        '9:00',
        '9:30',
        '10:00',
        '10:30',
        '11:00',
        '11:30',
        '12:00',
    ];

    return view('Club.reservacion.paso2');

}
```

If i run the code as is, it outputs an exception of some data i use in the views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will return $horas to your view.

```
return view('Club.reservacion.paso2', compact('horas');
```